# Video on external display while app UI on device

Tags: xamarin.ios

Is it possible to play video on an external display via an HDMI connector and Apple TV while having my own app UI on the device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, as the content displayed on the external display can either mirror the current app window, or show different windows.

The [Multiple Display Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012555-CH1-SW1) from Apple describes the process of implementing this pretty well. You may also want to look into the [AirPlay Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AirPlayGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011045) (in the case that the external display is AirPlay-enabled) for displaying video on the Apple TV.